# Code to decrypt the encrypted SHA256 code into string in crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++

I am using crypto++ to encrypt and decrypt the string .The code is shown below.
The code encrypts the username and password .But I don't know how to I decrypt it one again into string. What is the code to decrypt the encrypted SHA256 code into string.
Can any one help me.

```
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/base64.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
  byte digest[CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE];
  std::string username, password, salt, output;
  std::cout << "Enter username: ";
  std::getline(std::cin,username);
  std::cout << std::endl << "Enter password: ";
  std::getline(std::cin,password);
  salt = username + password;

  hash.CalculateDigest(digest,(const byte *)salt.c_str(),salt.size());

  CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
  CryptoPP::StringSink *SS = new CryptoPP::StringSink(output);
  encoder.Attach(SS);
  encoder.Put(digest,sizeof(digest));
  encoder.MessageEnd();

  std::cout << "The username/password salted hash is => " << output << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function - what you're asking is infeasible *by design*.

Comment: Also take a look at the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is not performing **encryption**, as the commentors already pointed out, but **hashing**. The central difference is that hashing, by design, is not reversible cheaply. This is important in password applications because you do explicitly not want to store the user's passwords in any accessible form, but only check against them.

So, in short words: You cannot "decrypt" your hash.

When you want to check a supplied password for correctness, you hash it again like in your code and compare the hash against the hash of the original password.

Comment: "... and compare the hash against the hash of the original password" - be sure to use Crypto++'s `VerifyBufsEqual` to avoid timing attacks on the comparison.